# Attempt to invoke virtual method 'boolean android.webkit.WebView.canGoBack()' on a null object reference

Tags: android, nullpointerexception, android-webview

My app loads up the fragment with the webView in it but when i try to press the back button. It crashes saying the web is null. I don't know why. Please help. Can i use an accessor like in the WebViewFragment

MainActivity

```
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentManager;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentTransaction;
import android.webkit.WebView;

public class MainActivity extends FragmentActivity {

    WebView mWebView;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        FragmentManager fragmentManager = getSupportFragmentManager();
        FragmentTransaction fragmentTransaction = fragmentManager.beginTransaction();
        WebViewFragment webViewFragment = new WebViewFragment();
        fragmentTransaction.replace(R.id.mainFragment, webViewFragment);
        fragmentTransaction.commit();
    }

    @Override
    public void onBackPressed() {

            if(mWebView.canGoBack()) {
                mWebView.goBack();

            }
    else
        {
            super.onBackPressed();
        }
    }

}
```

WebViewFragment

```
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.webkit.WebSettings;
import android.webkit.WebView;
import android.webkit.WebViewClient;

public class WebViewFragment extends Fragment {

    private WebView mWebView;


    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_main, container, false);

        mWebView = (WebView) view.findViewById(R.id.webView);

        WebSettings webSettings = mWebView.getSettings();
        webSettings.setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
        mWebView.loadUrl("https://www.google.co.uk/");
        mWebView.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient());

        return view;
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Your `mWebView` is defined inside `WebViewFragment.java`, `mWebView` in `MainActivity.java` is a different object and the value is null. So `mWebView.canGoBack()` will get error because `mWebView` is a null object.

You should modify `onBackPressed()` in MainActivity.java, e.g.:

```
@Override
public void onBackPressed() {
    Fragment webview = getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentByTag("webview");

    if ( (webview instanceof WebViewFragment) && WebViewFragment.canGoBack() ) {
            WebViewFragment.goBack();
    } else {
        super.onBackPressed();
    }
}
```

Also, add an unique identify fragment tag to the 3rd argument of line `fragmentTransaction.replace(...)`  in MainActivity.java, e.g. "webview":

```
fragmentTransaction.replace(R.id.mainFragment, webViewFragment, "webview");
```

Then, make `mWebView` static inside `class WebViewFragment`:

```
private static WebView mWebView;
```

And ensure you've defined this 2 static methods inside `class WebViewFragment`:

```
public static boolean canGoBack(){
    return myWebView.canGoBack();
}

public static void goBack(){
    myWebView.goBack();
}
```